# mysql LAST_DAY() only reads 1 subquery result, how to process all results? using joins?

Tags: mysql, date, join, subquery, case

I have an insurance policies table like this:

```
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | cancellation_val | cancellation_interval | expire_date |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| 1  | 30               | day                   | 2019-06-09  |
| 2  | 2                | month                 | 2019-12-01  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get the ids of the policies that are going to expire based on cancellation, from today and within 4 months, calculating the last day of the month, like this pseudo-code:

'today' <= LAST_DAY( expire_date - cancellation_val/interval ) < 'today + 4 months'

Being not a pro I think I should use JOINs but I don't know how, after days of trying the only thing I achieved was this:

```
SELECT LAST_DAY(
    DATE_FORMAT(
        STR_TO_DATE(
            (SELECT CASE cancellation_interval 
            WHEN "day" THEN date_sub(expire_date, INTERVAL cancellation_val DAY)
            WHEN "month" THEN date_sub(data_scadenzaexpire_date, INTERVAL cancellation_val MONTH)       
            END
            AS newDate
            FROM insurance WHERE id=2
            ), '%Y-%m-%d'
        ), '%Y-%m-%d'
    )
)
```

This is working but I don't need the "WHERE id=2" clause (because I need to process ALL rows of the table), and if I remove it I got error "subquery returns more than 1 row".
So how I can proceed? And using the result to stay between 'today' AND 'today + 4 months' ?
I think with some kind of JOIN I could do it in a easier way but I don't know how.
Thank you all

Comment: You don't need the subquery. And you don't need `DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE( ... ))`.

Comment: It's also not clear why you want to use `LAST_DAY()`. For me it doesn't make sense. If you have `expire_date = 2019-06-20`, `cancellation_val = 14` and `cancellation_interval = day`  - you will get `newDate = 2019-06-30` which is **after** `expire_date`.

Comment: There's no need for a join. We are returning rows from a single table. A single SELECT will do it. I concur with @PaulSpiegel comments. (The first cut query in my answer omitted the LAST_DAY function, as well as the DATE_FORMAT and STR_TO_DATE functions. Barmar caught the missing LAST_DAY function (it is in the title of the question) so I added it ...  the structure of query is the same, we are just quibbling over the expression to generate the "newdate" value

Comment: Hi all and thank you all VERY VERY MUCH for your help and the speed of reply. I agree with you Spencer, all of you gave the right solution only in different ways or omitting something but no problem, I understood what you all mean. I do not care about STR_TO_DATE or DATE_FORMAT but i need the LAST_DAY function, don't ask me why Paul Spiegel but the customer needs that (even if expiration date is for example 2019-05-15, the insurance company works with the last day of the month returned after the calculations). I still need to check and try answers but I think I am goin to select yours spencer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the structure of the query, not the `LAST_DAY` function.

We want to return the `id` values of rows that meet some condition.  So the query would be of the form:

```
SELECT t.id 
     , ... 
  FROM insurance t 
 WHERE ... 
HAVING ...
```

Introducing another `SELECT` keyword basically introduces a subquery. There are restrictions on subqueries... in the SELECT list, a subquery can return a single column and (at most) a single row.

So let's ditch that extra `SELECT` keyword.

We can derive the `newdate` as an expression of the SELECT list, and then we can reference that derived column in the `HAVING` clause. The spec said we wanted to return the `id` value, so we include that in the SELECT list. We don't have to return any other columns, but for testing/debugging, it can be useful to return the values that were used to derive the `newdate` column.

Something like this:

```
SELECT t.id
     , LAST_DAY(
         CASE t.cancellation_interval
         WHEN 'day'    THEN  t.expire_date - INTERVAL t.cancellation_val DAY
         WHEN 'month'  THEN  t.expire_date - INTERVAL t.cancellation_val MONTH
         ELSE t.expire_date
         END
       ) AS newdate
     , t.expire_date
     , t.cancellation_interval
     , t.cancellation_val
  FROM insurance t
HAVING newdate >= DATE(NOW()) 
   AND newdate <= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 4 MONTH
 ORDER 
    BY newdate ASC
```

---

We don't have to include the `newdate` in the SELECT list; we could just replace occurrences of `newdate` in the `HAVING` clause with the expression.

We could also use an inline view to "hide" the derivation of the newdate column

```
SELECT v.id
     , v.newdate
  FROM ( SELECT t.id
              , LAST_DAY(
                  CASE t.cancellation_interval
                  WHEN 'day'    THEN  t.expire_date - INTERVAL t.cancellation_val DAY
                  WHEN 'month'  THEN  t.expire_date - INTERVAL t.cancellation_val MONTH
                  ELSE t.expire_date
                  END
                ) AS newdate
           FROM insurance t
       ) v
 WHERE v.newdate >= DATE(NOW()) 
   AND v.newdate <= DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 4 MONTH
 ORDER 
    BY v.newdate ASC
```

Comment: You're not using `LAST_DAY()` to get the last date of the month.

Comment: good catch, Barmar...  i was focused on structuring the query. we can make that adjustment. standby.

Comment: Thank you very much, I will end up with a mix of all of your answers but I choose yours as answer because of your effort and kindness on explaining it. I just do not have clear what's the difference between WHERE and HAVING but I will study it.

Answer (score 0):

check this query: remove the **HAVING** Line to see all rows

```
SELECT 
IF(cancellation_interval = 'day',
        i.expire_date - INTERVAL i.`cancellation_val` DAY,
        i.expire_date - INTERVAL i.`cancellation_val` MONTH
    ) as cancellation_day,
    i.*

FROM `insurance` i
HAVING cancellation_day < NOW() + INTERVAL 4 MONTH;
```

**SAMPLES**

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT IF(cancellation_interval = 'day', i.expire_date - INTERVAL i.`cancellation_val` DAY, i.expire_date - INTERVAL i.`cancellation_val` MONTH ) as cancellation_day, i.* FROM `insurance` i HAVING cancellation_day < NOW() + INTERVAL 4 MONTH;
+------------------+----+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| cancellation_day | id | cancellation_val | cancellation_interval | expire_date |
+------------------+----+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| 2019-05-10       |  1 |               30 | day                   | 2019-06-09  |
+------------------+----+------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: I am sorry I can't mark as useful your answer because of my low reputation, but thank you, my final query will be a mix of your answers. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

When you use a `SELECT` query as an expression, it can only return one row.

If you want to process all the rows, you need to call `LAST_DAY()` inside the query, not on the result.

```
SELECT *
FROM insurance
WHERE CURDATE() <= LAST_DAY(
    expire_date - IF(cancellation_interval = 'day', 
                    INTERVAL cancellation_val DAY, 
                    INTERVAL cancellation_val MONTH))
AND LAST_DAY(expire_date - IF(cancellation_interval = 'day', 
                                INTERVAL cancellation_val DAY, 
                                INTERVAL cancellation_val MONTH)) < CURDATE + INTERVAL 4 MONTH
```

Comment: I am sorry I can't mark as useful your answer because of my low reputation, but thank you, my final query will be a mix of your answers. Thanks again